# Jacoco code coverage for Karate tests which are executing on mock server

Tags: code-coverage, karate, jacoco

We have springboot project with gradle. We have Karate API tests which are executed using mock server and mock APIs. We want to check code coverage for these tests using Jacoco plugin.
After execution, code coverage is always shown as 0 whereas code coverage for unit tests is shown correctly. Our unit tests dont require any mock server for execution.
Can you let me know how I can get code coverage for Karate API tests.

Comment: code coverage is hard if you are trying to instrument non-java code, or if the java code is in a different maven project. kindly search previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+jacoco